# How to programmatically collapse a grouped Kendo Grid- angular 8?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, grouping, kendo-ui-angular2

I have the following Kendo Grid on my angular 8 app where I have implemented Grouping. The grid by default appear with all groups expanded.

How can I programmatically collapse all groups so that the result looks like the following image after initialization?

[image]

Below is my code:

```html
<kendo-grid (dataStateChange)="dataStateChangeResources($event)"
              *ngIf="gridViewResources"
              [data]="gridViewResources"
              [group]="stateResources.group"
              [groupable]="{ showFooter: true }"
              [pageSize]="stateResources.take"
              [pageable]="true"
              [skip]="stateResources.skip"
              [sort]="stateResources.sort"
              [sortable]="{ mode: 'multiple' }"
  >

    <kendo-grid-column [width]="100" field="type" title="Type"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column [width]="100" field="item" title="Item"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column [width]="100" field="shift" title="Shift"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column [width]="100" field="plannedCost" title="Planned Cost">
      <ng-template kendoGridGroupHeaderColumnTemplate let-aggregates="aggregates" let-group="group">
        <span title="Planned Qty">
             {{ numberWithCommas(aggregates.plannedCost.sum) }}
        </span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template kendoGridGroupFooterTemplate let-aggregates let-group="group">
        <span title="Planned Qty">
             {{ numberWithCommas(aggregates.plannedCost.sum) }}
        </span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template kendoGridFooterTemplate>
        TOTAL = {{numberWithCommas(sumResourcesPlannedQty)}}
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

The TS code is:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PlanningService} from '../../services/planning.service';
import {SeriesLabels} from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';
import {aggregateBy, DataResult, process, State} from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import {DataStateChangeEvent} from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-planning-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './planning-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planning-dashboard.component.css']
})


export class PlanningDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  gridDataResources: any[];
  public seriesLabels: SeriesLabels = {
    visible: true,
    padding: 3,
    font: 'bold 14px Arial, sans-serif'
  };
  public gridViewResources: DataResult;

  public aggregatesResources: any[] = [{field: 'plannedCost', aggregate: 'sum'}, {field: 'actualCost', aggregate: 'sum'}];
  public stateResources: State = {
    skip: 0,
    take: 15,
    group: [{field: 'type', aggregates: this.aggregatesResources}]
  };

  constructor(private service: PlanningService) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllResources(9269);
  }

  getAllResources(workOrderId: number) {
    this.service.getAllResources(workOrderId).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.gridDataResources = response;
        this.loadDataResources();
      }
    );
  }

  public dataStateChangeResources(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    if (state && state.group) {
      state.group.map(group => group.aggregates = this.aggregatesResources);
    }
    this.stateResources = state;
    this.gridViewResources = process(this.gridDataResources, this.stateResources);
  }

  numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toLocaleString('en', {useGrouping: true});
  }

  private loadDataResources(): void {
    this.gridViewResources = process(this.gridDataResources, {group: this.stateResources.group});

  }

  public get sumResourcesPlannedQty() {
    const aggregateResult = aggregateBy(this.gridDataResources, [{aggregate: 'sum', field: 'plannedCost'}]);
    if (this.gridDataResources.length > 0) {
      return aggregateResult.plannedCost.sum;
    }
    return 0;
  }

}
```

I have searched for options by with no success. I would like to know how can I do this programmatically so that my grid is initially displayed collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let i = 0;

this.grid.collapseGroup(i.toString());
```

Here i is the position of row.

Answer (score 0):

I had to collapse row by row:

```js
public collapseAll() {
    this.gridDataResources.forEach((item, idx) => {
      this.topGrid.collapseRow(idx);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make the groups collapsed by default

```
  @ViewChild('grid') private grid;      
  public groups: GroupDescriptor[] = [{ field: "groupField" }];
  public gridData: GridDataResult;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getData();
  }

  getData(request: string) {
    this.service.getData(request)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      if (response.success) {
        this.gridGrouping(response.content);
        this.gridData = {
          data: this.gridGroup,
          total: response.totalRecords
        }
      }
    });
  } 

  gridGrouping(data){    
  this.gridGroup = groupBy(data, this.groups );
  this.gridGroup.forEach((_, index) => {
  this.grid.collapseGroup(String(index));
  });
  }
```

in this example when the data is passed to the `gridGrouping` method

1.The data is grouped by thegroup field

2.Then takes the grouped data and for each group it collapses the grid using the collapseGroup method native to kendo grids.

Hope this helps anyone looking to collapse groups by default

Thanks :)